# hostname not working in another Tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, dns

I have been using

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.12 www.example.com
```

in my hosts file in a previous tomcat server.

I downloaded another version of tomcat and the hostname `www.example.com` is not working it gives me 404 error I think there is a conflict when I tried for example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.12 www.example-s.com
```

It worked. But, I need my old hostname.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: 404 is not a DNS (hostname) problem, it's a page not found. So the host is there and your browser is connecting to it but tomcat does not find what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Please think twice:

You got an 404 error - which is an http status code!

This means that your DNS is working!

The [404 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means that your tomcat could not find the requested resource.

For example:

> http://www.example.com/

resulting in 404 error will mean that maybe you have deleted the

> Tomcat:webapps/ROOT

directory. Or you have changed the server.xml config.